# Finding the longest strings within a multidimentional array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, string-length

```js
let lists = ["Grocery", "Clothing", "Furniture"]; 
let items = [
  [
    "tomatoes",
    "cheese",
    "bread",
    "ham"
  ],
  [
    "shirt",
    "jacket",
    "jeans"
  ],
  [
    "sofa",
    "carpet",
    "bed"
  ]
];
```

So I have these two arrays. one in which the 'items' arrays belong to each array of lists. for example items[0] belongs to lists[0] etc.

to try to get the longest string from the arrays i tried this but it doesn't work....

```js
let longestString = (list) => {
  lists[items.reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b)];
  }
 console.log('Clothing's longest item is: ${longestString("Clothing")}`)
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: what should happen, if you have more than one same length string?

Comment: oh my bad. basically: Clothing's longest item is: jacket
console.log('Clothing's longest item is: ${longestString("Clothing")}`)

Comment: You have not answered Nina's Q :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the method you can use to ding the longest string in an array

```
function findLongest(array) {
  var currentMax = "";
  for (string of array) {
      if (string.length > currentMax.length) {
          currentMax = string
      }
  }
  return currentMax;
}
```

then, you can use this function on each of the arrays in "items".
I'll leave that one to you ^^

Answer (score 0):

You could map the array by taking an array of strings as result set.

```js
var lists = ["Grocery", "Clothing", "Furniture"],
    items = [["tomatoes", "cheese", "bread", "potatoes"], ["shirt", "jacket", "jeans"], ["sofa", "carpet", "bed"]],
    result = items.map(a => a.reduce((r, v) => {
        if (!r || r[0].length < v.length) {
            return [v];
        }
        if (r[0].length === v.length) {
            r.push(v);
        }
        return r;
    }, undefined));

lists.forEach((l, i) => console.log(`${l}'s longest item${result[i].length === 1 ? ' is' : 's are'} ${result[i].join(', ')}.`));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let lists = ["Grocery", "Clothing", "Furniture"]; 
let items = [
  [
    "tomatoes",
    "cheese",
    "bread",
    "potatoes"
  ],
  [
    "shirt",
    "jacket",
    "jeans"
  ],
  [
    "sofa",
    "carpet",
    "bed"
  ]
]; 

var listsObj = lists.reduce( (obj, k, idx) => {
  obj[k] = items[idx].reduce( (res, i) => (res.length > i.length ? res : i), '' );
  return obj;
}, {} );

lists.forEach(k => console.log(`${k}'s longest item is: ${listsObj[k]}.`));
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to first find the index in `lists` that corresponds to the given `list`, and then apply the `reduce` call on that particular sub array:

```js
const lists = ["Grocery", "Clothing", "Furniture"]; 
const items = [["tomatoes", "cheese", "bread", "potatoes"], ["shirt", "jacket", "jeans"], ["sofa", "carpet", "bed"]]; 

const longestString = (list) => 
    items[lists.indexOf(list)].reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b);
console.log(`Clothing's longest item is: ${longestString("Clothing")}`)
```

It would however be a better data structure if you would store the list name and the corresponding items *together*:

```js
const lists = {
    Grocery: ["tomatoes", "cheese", "bread", "potatoes"],
    Clothing: ["shirt", "jacket", "jeans"],
    Furniture: ["sofa", "carpet", "bed"]
}; 

const longestString = (list) => 
    lists[list].reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b);
console.log(`Clothing's longest item is: ${longestString("Clothing")}`)
```

Answer (score -1):

try below code snippet

```js
let lists = ["Grocery", "Clothing", "Furniture"]; 
let items = [
  [
    "tomatoes",
    "cheese",
    "bread",
    "ham"
  ],
  [
    "shirt",
    "jacket",
    "jeans"
  ],
  [
    "sofa",
    "carpet",
    "bed"
  ]
];

lists.forEach( (category, index) => {   
  let longest = items[index].reduce(function (a, b) { 
         return a.length > b.length ? a : b; 
      });
 
 console.log(`${category}'s longest item is: ${longest}`); 
 });
```